# AOP with Spring controller Function using customer Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

I have a use case where I want to intercept the Spring controller functions that are annotated with my Custom annotation. Let's call my annotation @CustomerAnnotation.

I have a controller MyController

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

@CustomerAnnotation
@RequestMappint("/test")
public void test() {
  // SOME CODE
}
```

My AspectJ class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomImpl implements CustomAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(CustomerAnnotation)")
    @Override
    public Object testAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {

        System.out.println("Inside annotaion");

        try {
            Object returnObj = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
            return returnObj;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
    };

}
```

Bu whenever I call my API i get the following exception :

```
The mapped controller method class 'com.controller.MyController' is not an instance of the actual controller bean instance 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154'. If the controller requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.
HandlerMethod details:
```

My CustomerAnnotation class:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CustomerAnnotation {

}
```

Any solutions ?

I have tried using the same logic on my service functions and it works there.

Update: When I add @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) it gives following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class
```

Please help

Comment: Please show your @CustomerAnnotation code.

Comment: @ViníciusCarneirodeBrito Done

Comment: Are you using any xml mapping file ??

Comment: @Nithin xml mapping for what?

Comment: Show your AspectJ configuration.

Comment: try adding `@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` above `@Around` annotation.

Comment: @ViníciusCarneirodeBrito what do you mean by aspectJ config ?

Comment: @Nithin does not work

Comment: Try my solution!

Comment: Answering "does not work" to every suggestion or answer is not very helpful. So if you fail to describe your problem well enough, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub and we can see for ourselves.

Comment: @kriegaex added

Comment: are you using @Controller on your controllers?

Comment: I cannot see any link to a GitHub repo. So where did you add it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaConfig use "@EnableAspectJAutoProxy" from "import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy" at class level in your configuration class.

Comment: I get the same exception

Comment: The mapped controller method class 'com.controller.MyController' is not an instance of the actual controller bean instance 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154'. If the controller requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.
HandlerMethod details: